# Euro '€' symbol not inserted correctly during Oracle SQL LOAD

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, sql-loader, dbms-output

I'm loading a csv file using sqlldr.
the file contains the symbol `"€"` which is inserted into a VARCHAR2 column. 
After the load, the database displays `'¿'` instead of the euro symbol.
I have specified the characterset in the control file during the load:

```
LOAD DATA 
CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
```

I'm runing all of this on a `Solaris` machine, which by the way can't display the '€' symbol, I gives me a `'.'` instead when I hit the key to get the €.

We are using the data for BI purposes, so we have to keep the varchar2 column, even though changing its type to nvarchar2 inserts the € symbol correctly.

> Can you suggest any other solution for the issue?

When I run locale command on the machin, I get :

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

and my NLS DATABASE PARAMETERS Are:

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8DEC
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
```

I have tried setting the NLS_LANG variable, but nothing seems to work.
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database is not configured to support the Euro character in a `VARCHAR2` column.  Your database's [`NLS_CHARACTERSET` of WE8DEC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/what-does-we8dec-mean) means that it uses the old [DEC MCS character set](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/dec-mcs.html).  That character set long predates the Euro character (it's even older than the ISO 8859-1 character set that also predates the Euro).  So you can't validly store a Euro character in a `VARCHAR2` column in your database.

You could change the database character set to something that supports the Euro character.  There are many such character sets but I would guess that ISO-8859-15, Windows-1252, or UTF-8 would be the easiest migrations.  Personally, I'd always prefer Unicode (UTF-8 which is the AL32UTF8 character set in Oracle) but you may have a reason to prefer a single-byte character set.  Alternatively, you could declare this column (and any others that need to use the Euro character) to be `NVARCHAR2` columns since your national character set supports Unicode.  Supporting `NVARCHAR2` columns may require changes to your front-end applications.  If you can change the database character set, that would be my strong preference over adding `NVARCHAR2` columns.

Comment: That's what I thought.
We settled for the nvarchar2 solution, since the customer wouldn't let us get any close to his database settings. 
Let's just hope that this has no repercussions on our front-end.
Thank you very much for your precise answer.